# HTTP Endpoint for WCF Service in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, azure-service-fabric

How do I get an HTTP endpoint, rather than a TCP one, exposed for a WCF Service hosted in Service Fabric? I've successfully got the sample provided by Microsoft in [WCF-based communication stack for Reliable Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf), but it uses a TCP endpoint. I've modified the `CreateServiceReplicaListeners()` code to try using a `BasicHttpBinding`, but get the following error:

```cs
Unhealthy event: SourceId='System.RA', Property='ReplicaOpenStatus', HealthState='Warning', ConsiderWarningAsError=false.
Replica had multiple failures in API call: IStatelessServiceInstance.Open(); Error = System.InvalidOperationException (-2146233079)
The ChannelDispatcher at 'http://localhost:0/43a1f131-a650-46f7-8871-02cc9821e0d1/6428f811-6944-4097-bf4a-0538355a1cb5-131275909542555280/81291d44-3c65-4d9b-8e0c-17a731103b5f' with contract(s) '"ICalculator"' is unable to open its IChannelListener.
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Wcf.Runtime.WcfCommunicationListener`1.b__0(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime.StatelessServiceInstanceAdapter.d__0.MoveNext()
```

Code in question:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Optional override to create listeners (e.g., TCP, HTTP) for this service replica to handle client or user requests.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A collection of listeners.</returns>
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None)
    {
        SendTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
        ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
        OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024,
    };
    binding.MaxBufferSize = (int)binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize;
    binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = Environment.ProcessorCount * binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize;
    return new[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener((context) =>
            new WcfCommunicationListener<ICalculator>(context, this, binding, "WcfServiceEndpoint"))
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide an address to the binding:

```
string host = context.NodeContext.IPAddressOrFQDN;
var endpointConfig = context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetEndpoint("CalculatorEndpoint");
int port = endpointConfig.Port;
string scheme = endpointConfig.Protocol.ToString();
string uri = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}://{1}:{2}/", scheme, host, port);
var listener = new WcfCommunicationListener<ICalculatorService>(
    serviceContext: context,
    wcfServiceObject: this,
    listenerBinding: new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None),
    address: new EndpointAddress(uri)
);
```

Make sure to define the endpoint in the service manifest:

```
<Resources>
    <Endpoints>    
      <Endpoint Name="CalculatorEndpoint" Protocol="http" Type="Input" Port="80" />
    </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

Notice the name of the EndPoint matches the name used in code.

Make sure you create a load balancing rule for the port (80 in my example)

A working example is [here](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.WcfCalc).

Comment: Had to use a little more from the example you provided, but that example works perfectly - thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to configure endpoint in the config file (like plain WCF), not in the code ? I've seen `CalculatorService.EndpointTypeFromConfig` method in the sample you have shared but cant found how it is used.